# Can't upload picture from Facebook to User Account picture - fbouath on Drupal

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7. I want to upload the profile picture from Facebook to the drupal account using the module Facebook OAuth (FBOAuth), but I can't.

When I try to get the picture from Facebook I get this two Notices:

1. Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in fboauth_create_user() (line 219 of /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/sites/all/modules/fboauth/includes/fboauth.fboauth.inc).
2. Notice: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Read error! in image_gd_get_info() (line 349 of /home/user/domains/example.com/public_html/modules/system/image.gd.inc).

The image get uploaded but the size of the image is 0KB.

Also when I call 'drupal_http_request('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $fbid . '/picture?type=large');'

I get this ->

```
[code] => -110
[error] => Connection timed out
[redirect_code] => 302
[redirect_url] => https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash1/3***0_1******_*******_n.jpg
```

Did someone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was wrong. There's a very simple solution and I don't know how I misswatched this

You have to check the checkbox 'Administer image styles' for 'AUTHENTICATED USER' under 'admin/people/permissions'.

And voila, it's uploading the pictures :)

This solved my problem.